# How can i make this mysql query ? If possible at all

Tags: mysqli

I have this table

```
itemname  property    value
------------------------------------------
A         size        big
A         color       red

B         size        big
B         color       blue

C         size        small
C         color       blue

D         size        small
D         color       blue

E         size        small
E         color       blue
```

Im creating a list like this: `SELECT property,value,COUNT(itemname),GROUP_CONCAT(itemname) FROM table GROUP BY property,value`

```
property     value     count
---------------------------------
size         big         2             (A,B)
size         small       3             (C,D,E)
color        red         1             (A)
color        blue        4             (B,C,D,E)
```

I want to filter the items which are BIG && SMALL && BLUE, how can i achieve this result ? (I MUST be specific about the property when addressing a value for filtering)

```
`SELECT 
  property,value,COUNT(itemname),GROUP_CONCAT(itemname)
 FROM 
  table 
 GROUP BY 
  property,value
 HAVING 
  ( property IN ('size') && value IN ('big','small') )
  && 
  ( property IN ('color') && value IN ('blue') )`
```

But this has no result, because it tries to match the row with size and color at the same time ?  My desired output in this case is to avoid the item A because it is red, like this:

```
property     value     count
---------------------------------
size         big         1             (B) A not here, because it is red
size         small       3             (C,D,E) no change because all are blue
color        red         0             (A) no red is selected, so this row should be 0 or not listed at all
color        blue        4             (B,C,D,E) all the 4 are big or small and blue
```

Please someone help me out in this, i lost 2days wondering on the solution.
I might use CASE combined with HAVING ? Or i should address the WHERE instead somehow ?
Note: This table is actually not real, but if this question can be solved i can use it in my real tables which are a lot more complicated.

Comment: `itemname` should not be duplicated and field `property` should be columns.

Comment: what do you mean ? property is a column already. By the way as i said my goal is not to reorganize the table, just to find a solution to this problem, so i can use it in my real tables.

Comment: if the idea is not to normalize the data; you will have to suffer from the consequences. the way how the data is represented might suit noSQL, but not really SQL. the way of data-modelling is different there.

Comment: my real tables like this: ITEMS, PROPERTIES (size,color,and a hundred more), PROPERTYVALUES (black,big,10mm,medium,short,tall etc..) and PROPERTYCONNECTIONS where i connect the item id's to the properties and the values.

Comment: make `size` and `color` columns; then it would be something alike `SELECT *, COUNT(itemname) AS amount FROM table WHERE color="blue" AND size IN("big", "small");` (with optinal grouping) if one cannot run a query like this, one can assume the structure is sub-optimal. see https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: I dont want to do that. I have multiple property values for properties like: property 'compatible models' with values '10mm,15mm,20mm,30mm' for items, that case if i want to filter out the 15mm compatible models, i would have to query with string '%15mm%' would not be efficient, also every items would store the same strings over and over again like ITEM 1 shoe, propA,propvalueA,propvalueB,propvalueC, ITEM 2 shoe,propA again,propvalueA again,propvalueB again etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186111/discussion-between-ninet9-and-martin-zeitler).

Answer (score 0):

I figured a solution on my own, of course this example table is nonsense, the point is the way it had been solved.

```
`
SELECT  
  property,  
  value,  
  COUNT(t.itemname) AS count  
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    itemname 
  FROM 
    table 
  GROUP BY 
    itemname 
  HAVING 
    COUNT (CASE WHEN property='size' AND value IN ('big','small') THEN 1 END) >=1  
    && 
    COUNT (CASE WHEN property='color' AND value IN ('blue') THEN 1 END) >=1
   ) t
INNER JOIN 
  table ON table.itemname=t.itemname 
GROUP BY 
  property,value
`
```